# Getting "org.openqa.selenium.InvalidArgumentException: invalid argument: uniqueContextId not found" for sendkeys and click

Tags: java, selenium

I am getting "org.openqa.selenium.InvalidArgumentException: invalid argument: uniqueContextId not found" in most of the cases for click , sendkeys and waitForVisibility of elements. This was working fine earlier, recently facing this after upgrading chrome 105.

Comment: Same with waitForAngular